# How to set default value to sysdate in MySql?

Tags: mysql, default-value, ddl

I am going to create a table with a column storing Created_date which is of datetime datatype. And my aim is to set its default value as sysdate().

I tried

> CREATE TABLE `tbl_table` (
>     `created_date` datetime DEFAULT sysdate())

This gives me error saying not a valid default statement. I used similar logic in Oracle.
Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sysdate-is-now)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try
`CREATE TABLE tbl_table ( created_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW())`

But: `NOW` is different from `sysdate` and `TIMESTAMP` is different from `datetime`, keep this in mind.

Normaly you only can use constants for default-values. `TIMESTAMP` is the only column-type which supports a function like `NOW()`. See [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27645) for further information on the MySQL Bugtracker.

Comment: so there is no way for keeping it datetime?

Comment: I got few inform from [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) which is saying timestamp will be updated. But when this get updated? like whenever we touch that row even for a select query?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_table(     
     created_datetime      DATETIME DEFAULT   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     modified_datetime     DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Should do the trick.